# Editable table using Stipple UI

Tags: user-interface, web-applications, julia, stipple

I want to build a web app to interact with backend data processing. How can I write a editable table with stipple? I can’t find helpful documents and become struggling. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: As you've mentioned, Stipple seems rather lacking in documentation. I would suggest asking this question as an Issue on the Github repo, and if you get an answer, copy-pasting that here yourself so that it's useful to others in the future.

Comment: more information in https://discourse.julialang.org/t/editable-table-using-stipple-ui/71854

Comment: Summary of the information for later readers: "There isn’t an easy way to do this right now but [they]’d like to look into it and implement it." For now, PlutoGrids.jl offers an alternative option.